# windows 10 specific telnet disconnection issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have a problem with Windows 10 command prompt while using Telnet. I have a router that I can set its ethernet port speed using a command. When I use this command in Windows 7 and Ubuntu, the device gives me an "OK" response, indicating the settings are set. Unfortunately, the same configurations fail using Windows 10. After setting the command, I get "Connection to host lost." What I figure out, even if I remove the ethernet cable, it does not disconnect immediately on Windows 7 and Ubuntu, but it disconnects suddenly on Windows 10. Because of this, I cannot see the "OK" response with Windows 10.

Is there a way to prevent sudden disconnection on Windows 10 and wait a bit longer even though the ethernet cable is unplugged for a while when connected via Telnet?

I have tried working around with **TcpInitialRTT** and **TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions**, but could not find a working way.

Comment: While having nothing to do with your question, if the router supports SSH it should be used in lieu of `telnet` since `telnet` sends everything, including `root`'s password, as plain text with no encryption.

Comment: Thanks but telnet is my only option.